# Ruby MRI 2.0.0 - Standard Library gems versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm looking for information on the versions of the packages that compose the Ruby Standard Library (MRI 2.0.0). I'm specifically interested in the **json gem**.

It's part of the Ruby [Standard Library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/index.html), but it's also available as a gem: [rubygems](http://rubygems.org/gems/json), [home](http://flori.github.io/json/), [github](https://github.com/flori/json/tree/master).
In addition, the readme on github mentions two versions (pure ruby and C extension).

Is there some resource where I can find detailed information on the Standard Library? Authors, versions, homepages, etc?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at [Ruby's source-code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/4c2304f0004e9f1784540f3d36976aad9eab1f68) to determine versions.

Look in the "[ext](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/4c2304f0004e9f1784540f3d36976aad9eab1f68/ext)" folder to find the Std-Lib stuff.

Drill down into a particular class or module to find its version.rb file. For instance, [JSON's version.rb](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/4c2304f0004e9f1784540f3d36976aad9eab1f68/ext/json/lib/json/version.rb) says it's currently at version 1.7.7.

If you're worried about having the most recent version of JSON, from my experience it's not necessary. Ruby gems picked up the 1.8.1 version from the Ruby-gems repo and upgraded to it on my machine, even though 1.7.7 came with Ruby v2.0p353:

```
gem list json

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

json (1.8.1, 1.7.7)
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's exactly the situation I am in: **json 1.7.7** installed along with Ruby, but **json 1.8.1** pulled down from Rubygems when I `bundle install`'ed a repo I'm contributing to. I had already looked at the `version.rb` file in the main **json** repo (of course, at the latest commit is reads 1.8.1), but I was looking for data about what's included in a precise MRI version. Your answer really helps.

Comment: Rubygems and Bundler are sometimes at odds about what is the right version, because they don't necessarily use the same gem list on your machine. They're supposed to be blended together in the future which should make these sort of problems go away, or at least less frustrating.

Comment: And, periodically run `gem out`, inspect the list, and then `gem up` to update everything, or `gem up name_of_gem` to cherry-pick what you want to update.

Comment: Yes, I read about the upcoming merge of the 2 projects, although it shouldn't happen for at least other 3 years afaik. Anyway, I can see that not all the "packages" in the std-lib are present in the ext folder (I guess that the simple ones don't have an independent folder). Is there any reference about how the std-lib is organized? (what's available as a gem, what's not)